# We can say really big, and it makes the thing we're talking about bigger than the usual big. Is there a way of saying not so big?

Tags: grammaticality

But I don't want to be saying "It is not that big" -> it is bigger, but smaller than the usual

I want to know if there is a work of the same type as "really" that decreses the ammount of "bigness" (that's probably not a word).

For example:
That is a really big midget - almost normal sized.

That is a ____ big person - a big person that is almost normal, but still bigger than the usual.

Keep in mind that I just want to know if there is a word that we can put before the adjective "big" in order to make it more or less "intensive". I'm not looking for an alternative to what I'm trying to say.

Comment: He is _quite_ big.?

Comment: That is a _slightly_ big person?

Comment: Can't we say "That is a little big person"?

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but I wouldn't say that and never heard anyone saying that.

Comment: Me neither, but whatever, I need an answer :(

Comment: I'd say _slightly_ is a safer way of saying this. Dictionary definition: to a small degree; not considerably. Synonyms: a little, a bit, somewhat, rather, moderately, to a certain extent, faintly, vaguely, a shade, a touch

Comment: Ok, you got me, I agree with you

Comment: Why not *somewhat big*?

Comment: I wasn't aware that SE allowed duplicate usernames --I thought you were arguing with yourself!

Comment: I don't think somewhat big conveys the same meaning, my language is dumb and I'm starting to think it is totally different from the english language.

Comment: _Slightly big_ is not idiomatic. _Fairly big_ is.

Answer (score 5):

As others have pointed out, you can say "not so big" — as you just did. As others still have pointed out, you can reword to say "slightly bigger than average", or "bigger than usual" — again, as you just did.

But to actually answer your underlying general question, the word you are looking for, the one that fills the blank as the antonym of *really*, is [*somewhat*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/somewhat). A thesaurus will offer additional synonyms, like *a bit* or what have you. He is somewhat big. He is a bit big. He is somewhat stupid. He is a bit stupid.

Oh, and *big* means "fat". You're really looking for *tall* there.

Comment: Or *moderately*.

Comment: I'd cay that big applied to a person means "massive" -- which may be fat, muscle, or just general substantiality.

Answer (score 2):

So far as I can make out, the most suitable "qualifier/hedge" for OP's context is...

> *For a midget, he's **relatively** tall*

Exactly what constitutes the "relative" context isn't necessarily explicitly stated. For example, if I say *"OP's English is relatively good"* here on ELL, I probably mean *good by comparison with most people who post on ELL* (but probably not as good as a native speaker). But if I say the same on ELU, I'm more likely to mean *good by comparison with the average native speaker* (i.e. - *better* than most native speakers).

Answer (score 1):

On the face of it, this is an easy question --a modifier like *slightly* or *trifle* should work.  However, we often hear such phrases used as humorous understatement.  If I said "Have you had the dessert there --it's a *trifle big*," one might reasonable expect that the dessert is actually huge.

A lot of this comes down to context.  Usually we only point out things like size when they are exceptional, so that is the expectation unless context indicates otherwise.

> "My brother is only *slightly taller* than average."

In this case, the *only* cues us that the *slightly* is to be taken as literal and not as humorous understatement.

Comment: True, but I think that would be true of almost any adjective. Any adjective could be used ironically for humor or rhetorical purposes. "That piece of cake is a _little_ big." "That politician is _very_ honest." Etc. In speech we can usually tell whether a literal or ironic meaning is meant by tone of voice. In writing an ironic usage is sometimes indicates with italics or other typographical distinctions -- as I did here -- or the reader is expected to realize it from context.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's just where I've been (Michigan, Oregon, Alberta) but I would consider "not-so-big" to be smaller than just "big".

Personally, I would use "rather" or perhaps "kind of".

> He's **rather** big.
>
> He's **kind of** big.

Some people might object to "kind of" on principle, but "rather" is a solid choice here.

Comment: "kind of" (or "kinda") is informal, but it's the most natural option for my area (northeast US).

Comment: I agree that kinda is the go-to informal option, but there's some folks out there that have a strong distaste for it.

Answer (score 1):

- *somewhat big*
- *fairly big*
- *pretty big*
- *moderately big*

IOW, take *big* and stick an adjective in front of it that means *a little bit* or *to a moderate degree*.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's "not so big" - as in your question title!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The answer to the question is **"not so big"**

Comment: As in *The Not So Big House*, a book written by architect Sarah Susanka.  She has actually trademarked the phrase "Not So Big" as it relates to her books on residential design.  http://www.notsobighouse.com/